# Why this for loop is infinite loop despite a condition?

Tags: javascript, loops

This function below is to create array slice and push is giving infinite loop. Can anybody try to justify that.

```
function MyFunction(arr, size) {
  var  newArr = [];

  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i+size)    
   {  
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));

   }  
  return newArr;
}
```

I am able to achieve my requirement with below while loop, although it seems almost similar.

```
function MyFunction(arr, size) {
  var  newArr = [];
  var i = 0;
  while(i < arr.length)    
  {      
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i,i+size));
    i = i + size;  
   }  
  return newArr;

}
```

> *Sample Input*:- myFunction(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
>
> *Sample Output*:- [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]

Comment: `i+size` doesn’t change `i`. `i += size` does.

Comment: Just by comparing your two approaches , you can identify problem in 1st approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your for loop you are never incrementing your variable `i`. That is it.
`i++` auto increments `i` but `i+size` doesn't.

it should be 
`i=i+size` or `i+=size`;

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

Your for loop should be:-

```
function MyFunction(arr, size) {
  var  newArr = [];

  for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i = i+size)    
   {  
    newArr.push(arr.slice(0,size));

   }  
  return newArr;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I think `i+size` should be `i += size` or `i = i + size`.

In the first loop, you're never incrementing `i`.

**EDIT**

You may also want to change the body of the loop to match the `while` loop too.

E.g., putting it all together, this `for` loop should be the equivalent of your `while` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size) {
    newArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + size));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed break statement;

Comment: @RanchiRhino May I ask why you accepted the other (later) answer instead of mine? The two answers are nearly identical.